# thenThrow() not throwing an exception

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a method in `OneServiceImpl` class as follows. In that class I am calling an interface method from another class.

```java
public class OneServiceImpl {
    //created dependency
    final private SecondService secondService;
            
    public void sendMessage(){
        secondService.validateAndSend(5)
    }
            
}

public interface SecondService() {

    public Status validateAndSend(int length);
}
        
public class SecondServiceImpl {
        
    @Override
    public Status ValidateAndSend(int length) {
        if(length < 5) {
            throw new BadRequestException("error", "error");
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I am try to perform unit test on `OneServiceImpl` I am not able to throw a `BadRequestException`.

```java
when(secondService.validateAndSend(6)).thenThrow(BadRequestException.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your use case is, but I think you should write an own test to accept and test an exception.

```
@Test(expected = BadRequestException.class)
public void testValidateAndSend(){
    SecondService secondService = new SecondService();
    secondservice.ValidateAndSend(6); //method should be lowercase
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the case considering you didn't post a full example of code + unit tests, but your mock will throw only when you are passing `6` as parameter. When configuring the behaviour of your mock with `when` you are telling it to throw only when the `validateAndSend` method is called with parameter `6`.

```java
when(secondService.validateAndSend(6)).thenThrow(...)
```

In your code you have `5` hardcoded. So that mock will never throw for the code you have, because it's configured to react to an invocation with parameter `6` but the actual code is always invoking it passing `5`.

```java
public void sendMessage(){
    secondService.validateAndSend(5)
}
```

If the value passed to the mock is not important you could do something like the following, that will throw no matter what's passed to it:

```java
when(secondService.validateAndSend(any())).thenThrow(BadRequestException.class);
```

On the other hand, if the value is important and it has to be `5` you could change the configuration of your mock with:

```java
when(secondService.validateAndSend(5)).thenThrow(BadRequestException.class)
```